# laptop/notebook for Admin roadwarrior - requirements?

Tags: laptop

I'd like to have change of pace and still get things done which means that I'll have to look for a decent Laptop with some serious grunt that lets me develop, test and deploy.

I'm new to this road thingie, so I'd like to get input on selection, requirements and what else to look out for. I'd also be happy about model/hardware suggestions or user experiences.

As a reference, I'm currently in the max $1000 ballpark, tendig towards cost-effectiveness.

demand profile:

- LAMP programming (this means real code, not web pages ;) )
- Virtualization, mainly running xen as dom0 [for development / testing (up to live beta for small projects) ]
- uncomplicated linux drivers for graphics would be a bonus, I'd like to avoid too much kernel patching as required for some proprietory graphics drivers.

I'm looking at suse because of xen integration until ubuntu integrates xen again.

edit: still looking for input on device selection/suggestions and personal experiences. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Get a good solid server hosted somewhere you trust, and use a cheap Notebook with a good nonglare screen to remote in.

Doing any valuable work on a notebook on the road is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Yes. But: A) Backups. Lots of them. Always. B)Often working in rural area, bad connect. C)Any solution for fequently changing IP's (train-frequent disconnects between mobile cells)? D)Also, in my country, mobile data plans are capped at 5GB/mo.
Will look into it though.

Comment: Reliable work sessions I'd tend to go with a plain laptop solution instead of remote solution too. But I'd also have a firewire drive for external backups. I'd also want to look at a Mac since I'm happy with their ability to boot and run from external drives for diagnostics and in case the internal drive fails, as well as their ability to boot into target disk mode themselves, but that's me.

Comment: If you're a business owner or working on code critical to the business, I'd look at encrypting that home directory and external drive as well.

Comment: And rotating a backup at home. In case the bag is stolen or destroyed.

Comment: Dropbox or equivalent helps to synchronise data across multiple computers (laptop, desktop, client workstation)
And a privacy filter. Invaluable when working on the subway.